# How do i correctly sort dates on R?

Tags: r

So, I am new to R, and I have been trying to sort dates for a graph in chronological order, for example, May 1st, 2020, May 2nd, 2020, and so on. I wrote the code below, but when I run the code, I am not getting all the dates linked to each bar and I am given only the months.

```
gplot(data = d, mapping = aes(x = Date, y = Proportion, group = 1 )) +
  geom_col(group = 1) + facet_grid(rows=vars(Group)) + 
  labs(x = "Date", y = "Read proportion (%)") + theme_light() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(colour = "grey20", 
                                   size = 6, angle = 45, 
                                   hjust = 0.5, vjust = 0.5), 
        axis.text.y = element_text(colour = "grey20", size = 6),
                                   text = element_text(size = 8))
```

Comment: _If_ your dates are actually _parsed_ as `Date` in R, then everything happens 'automagically'.  So please use the search function to learn about 'parse character as date' or 'read data as dates' etc.  It is also likely you meant to show `ggplot` (two 'g') but we cannot be sure as you did not supply a reproducible example.

Comment: It helps reproduce the problem when the post includes a data set.
An effective way to include one is `dput(d)`.
Run dput, then paste the output into your question.
See [rdocumentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/dput).
If your object is a vector, matrix, table, or data frame and is large,
`d |> head() |> dput()` will help give manageably sized output.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow! To check if your Date variable, is parsed as date: `library(lubridate) is.Date(d$Date) is.POSIXt(d$Date) `and hopefully one test is true

Answer (score 0):

Following up on my comment here is a *reproducible* approach.

#### Data

```
> set.seed(42) 
> d <- data.frame(Date=as.Date("2022-01-01")+0:29, 
                  Proportion=cumsum(rnorm(30)), 
                  Group=sample(1:2, 30, TRUE))0, TRUE))  
> head(d)
         Date Proportion Group   
 1 2022-01-01    1.37096     1   
 2 2022-01-02    0.80626     2   
 3 2022-01-03    1.16939     2 
 4 2022-01-04    1.80225     2 
 5 2022-01-05    2.20652     2 
 6 2022-01-06    2.10040     2   
>
```

#### Your Plotting Code (typo corrected)

```
> library(ggplot2)
> ggplot(data = d, mapping = aes(x = Date, y = Proportion, group = 1 )) + 
   geom_col(group = 1) + facet_grid(rows=vars(Group)) + 
   labs(x = "Date", y = "Read proportion (%)") + theme_light() + 
   theme(axis.text.x = element_text(colour = "grey20",     
                                    size = 6, angle = 45,  
                                    hjust = 0.5, vjust = 0.5), 
         axis.text.y = element_text(colour = "grey20", size = 6), 
                                    text = element_text(size = 8))
```

#### Output

[image]

Comment: You are welcome.  If they are helpful, please feel free to follow common practice on StackOverflow to maybe a) accept the answer (click on the 'tickmark') for which you get karma points too and maybe b) upvote the answer (click on the 'up-triangle') as this karma system is what helps StackOverflow sort better answers.